# My MacBook Pro doesn’t wake up after sleep mode

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, power

I have a MacBook Pro 13" (2013). After it goes into sleep it does not wake up. I see the tabulator key light goes on if I press it, but the monitor stays black. I can only restart the Mac by pushing the on/off key.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this you should try to do a PRAM and an SMC reset. You can see how to do that [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) and [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295). Don't worry you won't loose any data.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and did everything everybody recommended, including a clean reinstall. I found a workaround- Empty the Caches daily or every other day. Turn on Enable the Develop Menu
Choose Safari > Preferences, and click Advanced.
At the bottom of the pane, select the “Show Develop menu in menu bar” checkbox.

I do not know why this works but it does for me. And if I forget to empty the cache for an extra day I have the gray screen is back.